# How can we perform double click in protractor for Firefox

Tags: protractor

I am using Firefox 57.0.4 (64-bit) with selenium 2.53.1 and protractor 5.2.2 and i am using chrome as my default browser.
I have used below codes to implement double click.Its working in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox.

```
browser.actions().doubleClick(element(by.css(locator))).perform();
```

and

```
var ele=element(by.css(locator));
browser.actions().mouseMove(ele).mouseMove({x: 50, y: 0}).doubleClick().perform();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Firefox 59(Nightly).Double click is working in it.